# Unable to make the text responsive on website

Tags: html, web

I'm having issues in making a piece of text on my website, which will be part of the navigation system, become responsive. Currently, the text is just sitting there and will not move when I readjust my browser.

Here is my HTML:

```
<div id="apDiv1">
<div class="wrapper1">
  <h2>Home</h2>
</div></div>
```

Here is my CSS:

```
.wrapper1{

width:100%;
max-width:960px;
margin:0 auto;

}
```

Comment: What exactly do you expect it to do when you "readjust your browser"?

Comment: Thanks for your reply, I mean as in, when I move readjust the browser size I want the text to also move, for example if you're on a smaller browser or mobile for it to adjust itself, I know I am supposed to set it to 100% but that's it.

Comment: Continued - You see how if you was to resize the browser on StackOverflow, the menu and the text etc would move along with it, that's what I'm trying to achieve.

Comment: Maybe your solution is as simple as this: http://fittextjs.com/

Answer (score 1):

You expect your text to move when you change the size of your browser window.

However, if the text is left adjusted (as you your case), it will always be on the left, regardless of the window size. So you should not expect it to "move".

Comment: Thanks for your response, but could you tell me where I've set it as "left adjusted" so I can change it?

Comment: It's the default. Try adding `text-align:center` to your css class.

Comment: Thanks Mundi, but that still isn't doing anything.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to center the div on-screen?  I'm not sure what you mean by move the text.
If you want to center the div ".wrapper1", add `position: relative` to it.

If you want to center the  text, make it `text-align: center;`

Comment: Thanks for your response, I've added the "position: relative" as you've recommended but it isn't doing anything, the text is still in the same position.

Also, I mean as in, you know how you would have a navigation system and expect it to readjust itself if you resize the browser, mine doesn't do that, so I would have the text as part of the navigation system, resize my browser and you wouldn't be able to see that "home" link, I want it to follow the position so the user can see it on the screen if the browser is resized. Hope that's clear enough.

Comment: if I understand correctly, you want the div to be centered, right - but only when the window is wider than 960px?

Comment: Added an answer for centering the h2 text

Comment: I want the div to follow through the flow of the page, for example inside my div there is text, when I drag the browser from the sides, I want the text to also move along with it, so it isn't just sitting there and disappearing, currently the text is at the top as it's part of the navigation system.

Comment: Can you make a jsfiddle?  It worked in my tests so I'm thinking I'm missing some information.

Comment: Here's a fiddle with text-align: center on the h2 tag: http://jsfiddle.net/66ZRx/

Comment: I haven't used a jsfiddle before, should I put the entire html/css code in it & Save/link to you? (The HTML is relatively small)

Comment: When you go to jsfiddle.net, just paste the code in then hit the "Save" button, and paste that on here to share it

Comment: Is there a possibility I can record this and/or show you on my screen? it would be a lot more easier.

Comment: I'm not sure how that's done... there's an output tab on jsfiddle that shows the results

Comment: I can't figure it out, sorry... something odd and complex is going on

Answer (score 0):

Did you include the css file correctly in your html?

The following works as expected. You can base your debugging on that:

```
<html>
 <head>
  <style type="text/css"> .wrapper1 {color:red; text-align:center; width:100%;} </style>
 </head>
 <body>
  <div id="haha">
   <div class="wrapper1">
    <h2>Hello World.</h2>
   </div>
  </div>
 </body>
</html>
```